# mysqli not inserting or extracting data from the database properly

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've upgraded to PHP 7 and I've updated all of the MySQL functions to MySQLi and made a few minor tweaks most of what I've changed was in this class the dblayer:

```
/*
 * A DATABASE LAYER THAT HELPS PROGRAM EASILY MERGE WITH DIFFERENT DATABASE SERVERS
 */
class dblayer {
public $dbtype;
public $dbhost;
public $dbuser;
public $dbpass;
public $dbname;
private $dbconn;

public function __construct() {
    $this->dbconn = false;
    $this->dbtype = 'mysql';
    $this->dbhost = 'localhost';
    $this->dbuser = '';
    $this->dbpass = '';
    $this->dbname = '';
}

/*
 * CREATES A CONNECTION TO THE SERVER AND DATABASE
 */
public function connect() {
    if (! $this->dbconn) {
        
        switch ($this->dbtype) {
            
            case 'mysql' :
                
                $this->dbconn = mysqli_connect ( $this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass, $this->dbname );
                
                if (mysqli_connect_error ())
                    
                    die ( 'ERROR CONNECTING TO DATABASE. CONNECT ERROR (' . mysqli_connect_errno () . ') ' . mysqli_connect_error () );
                
                break;
        }
    }
}

/*
 * A GENERIC SELECT QUERY WITCH RETURNS A MULTIDIMENSIONAL RESULTS ARRAY
 */
public function select_query($sql) {
    $results = array ();
    
    if ($this->dbconn) {
        
        switch ($this->dbtype) {
            
            case 'mysql' :
                
                $query = mysqli_query ( $this->dbconn, $sql );
                
                if (mysqli_num_rows ( $query ) > 0) {
                    
                    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ( $query ) ) {
                        
                        $results [] = $row;
                    }
                } else {
                    
                    $results = false;
                }
                
                break;
            
            default :
                
                break;
        }
    }
    
    return $results;
}

/*
 * BASIC MODIFCATION QUERY SUCH AS UPDATE OR DELETE
 */
public function modify_query($sql) {
    if ($this->dbconn) {
        
        switch ($this->dbtype) {
            
            case 'mysql' :
                
                mysqli_query ( $this->dbconn, $sql );
                
                break;
        }
    }
}

/*
 * BASIC INSERT QUERY RETURNS NEW INCRIMENTED ID
 */
public function insert_query($sql) {
    $returnid = 0;
    
    if ($this->dbconn) {
        
        switch ($this->dbtype) {
            
            case 'mysql' :
                
                mysqli_query ( $this->dbconn, $sql );
                
                $returnid = mysqli_insert_id ( $this->dbconn );
                
                break;
        }
    }
    
    return $returnid;
}

/*
 * CLOSES DATABASE CONNECTION ON SCRIPT END
 */
public function __destruct() {
    if ($this->dbconn) {
        
        switch ($this->dbtype) {
            
            case 'mysql' :
                
                mysqli_close ( $this->dbconn );
                
                break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

I've tried looking for most obvious answers and the problem might lie somewhere else. I'm going to continue to find the problem but if you see anything that could help or could need fixing let me know.

---Edit---

Rivition1

> I'm using this to do a hand full of things but namely my problem is when I try to make a new user but on the website when I attempt to make a new user it brings you into the "signed in phase," but when you sign out you can't sign in. I've checked that database and there is no new entry there.  Also, I've tried to sign in as any of the users that already exist on the database and it doesn't work either.

Rivition2

> I've also changed mysql_real_escape_string to mysqli_real_escape_string in **A Lot** of places on my other classes.  Would this affect it drastically or does it basicly do the exact same thing???

-Thank you-

Comment: Hi, what you got and what you expected with your query?

Comment: What is exactly your question?

Comment: I'm using this to do a hand full of things but namely my problem is when I try to make a new user but on the website when I attempt to make a new user it brings you into the "signed in phase," but when you sign out you can't sign in. I've checked that database and there is no new entry there.  Also, I've tried to sign in as any of the users that already exist on the database and it doesn't work either.

Comment: `mysqli_num_rows ( $query ) > 0` is a *__MASSIVE__* anti-pattern.

Comment: Then What do you suggest?